# searching in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, search

i want to search in database in my android application. when i get a select query if its been or not  been in database its show nothing.

this is my code:

```
final String havy = edtSearch.getText().toString();

 btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Cursor cursor = G.dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM db WHERE info_title=" + "'" + havy + "'", null);
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(G.selectedItem.face, true);
                SearchActivity.this.finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "shows something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your cursor is not null and size is greater that zero, then iterate over the cursor.

Comment: i do that but the result is same